# How to fix my convert base who return str

Tags: c

I don't understand why my itoa don't work with a specific case,

```
typedef  t_number unsigned long long;
int     getnumber_length(t_number number, int base)
{
    int     length;

    length = 1;
    while (number)
    {
        length++;
        number /= base;
    }
    return (length);
}

char    *itoa(t_number number, int base)
{
    char    *str;
    int     length;
    int     i;

    if (number < 0)
    {
        number *= -1;
        ft_putchar('-');
    }
    length = getnumber_length(number, base);
    if (!(str = (char*)ft_strnew(length)))
        return (NULL);
    i = length - 1;
    while (number)
    {
        str[--i] = (number % base) + 48;
    //  str[i] = "0123456789abcdef"[str[i] % base];
        number /= base;
    }
    return (str);
 }
```

The specific case i when i passing `itoa(-652258, 8);`, my result is 1777777777777775406036.

But i should have 37775406036. Thanks for help :)

Comment: To begin with, don't forget that strings needs to be terminated.

Comment: As for your problem, this looks like a very good time to [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: its because it is not in base 10. negative numbers will not be represented the way you think, it will interpret the value unsigned using the twoscomplement bit representation as a 64bit unsigned number. From the doc: "f base is 10 and value is negative, the resulting string is preceded with a minus sign (-). With any other base, value is always considered unsigned."

Comment: Not really, @Rob.  The behavior of the standard library's `itoa()` isn't really relevant to the OP's custom implementation.  The OP's implementation in fact doesn't handle negative numbers at all, as its `number` parameter has an unsigned type, `unsigned long long`.  Negative actual arguments are converted to that type by the caller; they never reach the function as negative numbers (and so the `number < 0` test is vacuous).

Comment: @JohnBollinger but the 64 bit part is. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my result is 1777777777777775406036.
>
> But i should have 37775406036.

Count the bits.  Given that those are octal representations, the former has 64 significant bits, and the latter 32.

Now consider the type of your input parameter: `t_number`, a.k.a. `unsigned long long`.  That type is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide, and the result of converting a negative number representable by type `long long` to type `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to have the most-significant bit set, making all bits significant.  That's exactly what your actual result shows.

If you want to use 32-bit representation instead then I would suggest `#include`ing stdint.h and using type `uint32_t`.  I suggest using that type *instead of* your `t_number`, which is less clear about its size, but if you must, you can define `t_number` as `uint32_t`.